# Why the answer is unexpected upon input?

Tags: list, for-loop, if-statement

```
 l = ['sone.com']

 for a in l:
    if '@' and '.' in a:
        print('ok')
```

Result is coming to be ok. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if '@' and '.' in a:
        print('ok')
```

is causing the error, change it to

```
  if '@' in a and '.' in a:
        print('ok')
```

when you do `if '@'` on its own, it returns true.

Think of `if '@'` is the same as saying `if '@' = '@'`.

and when you use `and` the two variables need to be set individual condtions so ...

`if '@' in a and '.' in a`

notice the `if '@' in a` & `'.' in a`